# How do I rename a SharePoint virtual machine

Tags: sharepoint, moss, rename, virtual-machine

I am using virtual machines for development,but each time I need a new VM, I copy the file and create a new server, but I need a new name for the server to add it to our network.

After renaming the server, the Sharepoint sites have many errors and do not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Technet article that might be helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261986.aspx

If you are going to uninstall SharePoint check this article for more details about SQL Server rename: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a bunch of stuff you will need to do in regards of the unique computer SID, SQL Server etc.

These links will get you started:

http://paulhorsfall.co.uk/archive/2007/04/10/How-to-Create-a-Cloneable-SharePoint-Virtual-Machine.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2008/04/25/renaming-server-pc-with-sharepoint.aspx

http://dotnet.org.za/jpfouche/archive/2008/02/12/renaming-your-sharepoint-virtual-machine.aspx

I hope this helps, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another link that helped me a lot:http://www.sharepointblogs.com/mirjam/archive/2007/08/06/renaming-a-moss-server.aspx